# Prove language is not context-free using pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I have the following alphabet:
Σ = {0, 1, . . . , 9}
and the Language *L* defined as:

*L* = { abc | a + b = c}

where substrings *a*, *b* and *c* are interpreted as ordinary integers.

**My answer so far**:

Assume *L* is context-free. Then the pumping lemma for context-free languages applies to *L*.

Let *n* be the the constant given by the pumping lemma.

Let *z*=10^n20^n30^n clearly z ∈ L and |z| ≥ n

By the lemma we know that *z* = uvwxy with *n* ≥ |vwx| and  |vx| ≥ 1

There exists possibilities...

**My questions:**

I can see 8 possibilities where vwx can be within z. For example in the beginning including the 1 and overlapping with the initial 0^n. Another example the initial 0^n. Is this one way to think in this particular question? How can I pump and show that the result does not belong to L?

**Thank you for your time.**

Comment: Please ask each question on only one stack community. In this case, you are asking a question about CS theory and not about a programming mg problem, so your first choice (https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109195/prove-language-is-not-context-free-using-pumping-lemma) was correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think your choice of word works too, but I will choose a simpler one (for me) to show the same thing. You can probably adapt this to your choice of string.

Choose w = (1^p)(2^p)(3^p) where p is from the pumping lemma for context-free languages. First, note that 11...1 + 22...2 = 33...3 were all numbers have p digits. Now, there are exactly five simple cases for the position of vxy if w = uvxyz:

1. vxy consists only of 1. In this case, pumping down (removing at least one of the 1) must necessarily result in a string not in the language. Since no carry can occur on addition of any of the digits, the string must be divisible in three equal-length parts for a, b and c; these must have precisely the same number of digits. Removing 3k digits from the front therefore pulls in k of the 2s into a, and 2k of the 3s into b. But then, the least significant digit of a + b must be 5 which is not a symbol in w.
2. vxy consists of 1 and 2. In this case, pumping down (removing some number of 1 and 2) must necessarily result in a string not in the language. Since no carry can occur on addition of any of the digits, the string must be divisible in three equal-length parts for a, b and c; these must have precisely the same number of digits. Removing 3k digits from 1s and 2s must pull 3s into b. The least significant digit of a + b will therefore be at least 4 (since w contains no 0) and 4 is not a digit in w.
3. vxy consists of 2. The argument here is the same as in the second case above.
4. vxy consists of 2 and 3. Pumping UP in this case must eventually put 2 into both a and b so that the digits overlap, so we get the same 4/5 digit issue as above.
5. vxy consists of 3 only. Again, pumping UP in this case must eventually put 3 into b, causing the 4/5 digit issue.

Illustrations:

1. w = 1^p 2^p 3^p, pump down to 1^(p-3) 2^p 3^p, a = 1^(p-3) 22, b = 2^(p-2) 3, c = 3^(p-1), the least significant digit of a + b is 5, too high, can't be right.
2. w = 1^p 2^p 3^p, pump down to 1^(p-1) 2^(p-2) 3^p, a = 1^(p-1), b = 2^(p-2) 3, c = 3^(p-1), again the least significant digit, 4, is too high.
3. w = 1^p 2^p 3^p, pump down to 1^p 2^(p-3) 3^p, a = 1^(p-1), b = 1 2^(p-3) 3, c = 3^(p-1). Again, the least significant digit, 4, is too high.
4. w = 1^p 2^p 3^p, pump up to 1^p 2^(p+1) 3^(p+2), a = 1^p 2, b = 2^p 3, c = 3^(p+1). Now the least significant digit is too high.
5. w = 1^p 2^p 3^p, pump up to 1^p 2^p) 3^(p+3), a = 1^p 2, b = 2^(p-1) 33, c = 3^(p+1). The LSD is still too high.